# Why did China not seem to have cared about the Nanking Massacre?

Tags: world-war-two, japan, china

The Japanese really did horrible stuff to China's citizens, which peaked in the Massacre of Nanking. Dozens of women, regardless of the age, where raped and many more killed in really gruesome ways. Why did China not use this, after the second world war, to increase political pressure on Japan? What troubles me most is the fact that they didn't even really try to prosecute the responsible Japanese men.

Comment: "responsible Japanese men" [have been prosecuted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanking_Massacre#War_crimes_tribunals).

Comment: What leads you to believe that the Chinese don't care? I think that assertion is unsupportable.

Comment: You'll have to first show that the premise of your question is true. I will note there was that whole [civil war they were dealing with for years after WWII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_civil_war) which may have been a distraction and distortion. There was the [Nanjing War Crimes Tribunal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanjing_War_Crimes_Tribunal), but [Yasuji Okamura's sentence was commuted by Chiang Kai-shek to use him as a military advisor for the Chinese Nationalists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yasuji_Okamura#War_crimes_and_post-war_life).

Comment: Perhaps because it would have left the Chinese open to questions about what they did to fellow Chinese?

Comment: This question would be significantly improved if we understood why you think the Chinese did not care about Nanking.  I think we're all puzzled by that assertion.

Comment: @user25705 Stating that "dozens" of women were raped is an unfortunate understatement that could be considered offensive. I would suggest rephrasing that part of the question. Iris Chang, "The Rape of Nanking" (1997), pg. 6. mentions that "[a]n estimated 20,000-80,000 Chinese women were raped".

Comment: This question isn't as bad as it might appear. While the PRC is very vocal about Japan's war crimes nowadays, I've read that that wasn't the case soon after WWII.

Comment: Suggest you have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanking_Massacre#Effect_on_international_relations and then rephrase your question so that we can better understand what you are looking for exactly.

Answer (score 5):

Your perception is wrong, Japanese occupation and subsequent massacres are influencing Chinese politics, and Chinese conscience in general, even today. Close parallel could be made with Soviet (latter Russian) state of mind about WW2, Germany and Germans .

Terrible losses and terrible humiliation that China suffered in that period are not forgotten. But there is another thing. Like Soviet Union, China was on the other side of Iron Curtain. Former enemies (Japan and Germany) after the war became close allies of Western powers (chiefly US) . Both Soviet and Chinese part of the WW2 story was largely left untold in the West. During Cold War, and even now, West tends to minimize participation of those countries, and to somewhat dehumanize their victims like statistics. For example, in Western cinematography, there are numerous films about Jewish suffering in WW2. But Slavs are barely mentioned and Chinese almost not at all, despite the the fact that they suffered much larger casualties and actively participated in war effort.

Anyway, current Chinese foreign policy towards Japan (from 1980 to present) is mostly pragmatic. They were and still are interested in good economic relations. But they do have territorial disputes and strategic rivalry who is going to be dominant power in East Asia . Japan is still ally of US, and China is becoming main American rival on world stage. In that context, anti-Japanese sentiment in China is substantial, and historical grievances like Nanking massacre are often used in media and popular culture, especially because Japan tries sometimes to downplay them.

[China–Japan relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China%E2%80%93Japan_relations#1980s)

[China remembers Nanjing massacre](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/dec/13/china-remembers-nanjing-massacre)

[Anti-Japanese sentiment in China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Japanese_sentiment_in_China)

[Video of Nanjing massacre commemoration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHXnrS7TWms)

[Chinese anti-Japan movies](https://widerimage.reuters.com/story/chinas-world-of-anti-japan-war-films)

Comment: A good answer that would be even better if you include a few sources to support your assertions.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Some links added for better understanding of Chinese POV in this matter.

Comment: Thank you for those, particularly the video of the commemoration. I hadn't seen that one before.

Comment: One small indication that the Nanking Massacre is not forgotten today is the opening, in 2006, of the [John Rabe and International Safety Zone Memorial Hall](https://www.nju.edu.cn/_upload/tpl/01/c2/450/template450/img/index.htm). [John Rabe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Rabe) was a German businessman and Nazi Party member under whose leadership foreigners set up the [Nanking Safety Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanking_Safety_Zone) where tens of thousands of Chinese civilians were protected from the Japanese troops.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of reasons come to mind:

At the end of the war, Japan was devastated, probably more so than Germany. Most of their major cities had been severely damaged by fire raids. Their industry had been all but obliterated. Industrial infrastructure: power, rail transport, had been completely destroyed Their once thriving merchant fleet, critical to an island nation, was on the bottom of the ocean. There wasn't much for China to demand from Japan, even if they were in a position to do so.

When hostilities ceased, China almost immediately resumed a civil war between the Nationalists and Communists, a war the Communists won. The Chinese had more pressing matters to attend to.

Japan had been very cruel to China, beyond Nanking. Japanese troops committed [wholesale slaughter and destruction](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/untold-story-vengeful-japanese-attack-doolittle-raid-180955001/) in the aftermath of the Doolittle Raid, on Chinese suspected of aiding the flyers, or Chinese who just happened to be there. A very rough estimate of Japan's revenge on China for the Doolittle Raiders is in the 250,000 death range.

And the story of [Unit 731](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_731). An accurate death toll is hard to establish, but it is estimated to be in excess of 500,000 people killed.   It wasn't well publicized after the war, because the US wanted the technology. Japan had it's own WMD: biological weapons, and - the big breakthrough - they had perfected and tested (on the Chinese) delivery systems for those bioweapons: anthrax, bubonic plague, smallpox.

My father, who ran radar for the 14th USAAF in China during the war, related to me a story that illustrates the feelings between the Chinese and Japanese. A Japanese bomber had been dropping bombs on his base at Kunming at night. Never hit much of anything, but they might get lucky and kill someone, so he radioed another base and had them send down their P61 Black Widow night fighter. It shot up the bomber, which was seen to crash land.

Dad sent out a squad of soldiers to the crash site the next morning to see if anyone had survived, but the local Chinese got there first. They had nailed the now very dead aircrew to trees, while they were still alive.